# Storing a document in a different collection - Mongodb with symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, collections, symfony

Im trying to store a document in a different collection by using Mongodb and symfony2

This is my controller who sets the document into the db.

```
public function createAction(){
$post = new Post();
$post->setUrl('A Foo Bar');
$post->setTitle('asdf');
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$dm->persist($post);
$dm->flush();
return new Response('Created post id '.$post->getId());}
```

As you can see, this is the example for the official documentation on [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)

But the problem is that by default it creates the document into a Collection named as the class, in my case is Post(), so the collection name is Post. I will like to save the document into a Collection named for example charlies_posts or any string as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy :) In the definition of your document class just use the "collection" parameter.

Here is an exemple :

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document(
 *     collection="charlies_posts"
 * )
 */
class Post
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeahp, as you say we can define that as a parameter.

```
Documents\User:
  type: document
  db: my_db
  collection: charlies_post
```

In this case in the YAML mapping file a different collection may be selected but in my case i want to dinamically set the collection name because i have post related to the user so charlies posts should go to the charlies_post collection and peter posts should go to peter_post collection...

I suppose that there must be a method to set this but i cant find it..